# Parameters in python trouble

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the following code to print out the numbers of that string but it doesn't print anything.could someone please help a beginner coder out.

```
import re
def remove_letters(provided_string):
    provided_string="adf73390sdkfjh"
    new_string =  re.sub("[^0-9]", "", provided_string)
    return (new_string)
```

Comment: Is this all the code? You never call the function and never `print` anything. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Seems to work for me. The argument you provide is never used though, and always overwritten by your hard-coded string.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are calling the function? This seems to work fine.

```
import re

def remove_letters(provided_string):
    new_string = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", provided_string)
    return new_string

print(remove_letters("adf73390sdkfjh"))
```